# JS accordion - hide content when another one is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, accordion

I've been trying to hide one accordion content when another one is opened, tried all the ways, couldn't find one that fits my code. Any idea on how to do this?

JS:

```
$("body").on("click", ".accordian-trigger", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parents(".accordian-wrapper").toggleClass("active");
    $(this).parents(".accordian-wrapper").find(".accordian-pane").slideToggle();
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="accordian-wrapper">
    <a href="#" class="accordian-trigger bg-blue1">Tomografia Cone Beam de Alta Resolução</a>
    <div class="accordian-pane">
            <p>Programa de visualização OnDemand 3D dental , onde se pode realizar mensurações e analises mais apuradas do volume obtido.</p>
            <a href="requisicaoonline.html" class="btn">Agende seu horário</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.accordian-section { 
    background:  url(../demo-data/BG1.jpg); 
    background-size: cover; }

.accordian-pane {
    display: none; }

.accordian-wrapper {
    margin-bottom: 1px; }

.accordian-wrapper.active .accordian-trigger {
    background: #274DA8; }

.accordian-trigger {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: #78BCEE;
    padding: 15px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold; }
```

Comment: can you post your relevant HTML and CSS?

Comment: Sorry, for that

Comment: Edited the post

Answer (score 1):

```
$("body").on("click", ".accordian-trigger", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $(".accordian-pane").slideUp();
    $(this).next(".accordian-pane").slideDown();
});
```

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vxpBNV)

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks so much!